# Sort Author Names by Post Count

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

AUTHOR

```
Author_ID      Author_Name               
 -------------------------                      
1           name 1      
2           name 2    
3           name 3
 ---------------------------
```

POST

```
Post_ID      Author_ID
 -------------------------                      
1           1      
2           1    
3           2
4           3
5           3
6           3
 ---------------------------
```

I need a mysql query that counts the number of posts each author has and then sorts the authors largest to smallest.

My current MySQL only displays the names:

```
select * from AUTHOR
where author_status = '1' ORDER BY author_name DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT author.author_id, author.author_name, count(post.post_id) FROM AUTHOR, POST
    WHERE (author_status = '1')
    AND (author.author_id = post.author_id) 
GROUP BY author.author_id
ORDER BY author.author_name DESC;
```

Comment: I removed the ORDER BY line and this gave me the result I was looking for. Thx!